# iOS xib file difference comparison

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I pulled code from github and run code, and see the code change as listed in the picture. Please help me clarify what is this info is about, why this happens and does it have any side-effects. Thanks very much!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's nothing to worry about. When you open an xib it just updates the version number. It has no effect on the resulting xib and you can either revert the change or push it to your repo.

Edit:

Only effect it may have is causing conflicts when using version control but they're easy to resolve conflicts. It doesn't matter which version you decide to keep.

Comment: Thanks for your info